# Caldera Forms 'Custom Class' does not work (even on default wp theme)

Tags: wordpress

Reporting a possible bug here as I am too broke to buy a 'direct support' licence :p

The latest version of Caldera Forms (v. 1.5.2.1) does not show custom classes added to forms via the dashboard. I've tried it on a new install with a default (saved) form on the default twenty seventeen theme.

Can anybody else reproduce this issue or have a workaround?

[Click here for a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvjDV.jpg)

Comment: Can you please create support ticket here https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/caldera-forms as this is plugin bug/issue

Comment: Done thanks, was not aware of this forum :)